# jquery datepicker on angular with 2 different formats

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

I have a `jquery ui datepicker` on `angular` app,

It is defined like this:

```
app.directive('dwdatepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function(){
                element.datepicker({
                    onSelect:function (date) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        });
                    },
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-50:+0"
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now I want to store the value in $modelValue on **yyyy-MM-dd** format, and to show the value to the user on **dd/mm/yy** format.

How can I make it?

***How to combine the capabilities of jquery ui datepicker with the capabilities of angular?***

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onSelect` function you could do either of the following:

```
onSelect:function (date) {
   scope.$apply(function () {
      var isoDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', date));
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(isoDate);
   });
}
```

Or

```
onSelect:function (date, ) {
   scope.$apply(function () {
      var isoDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd',$(this).datepicker('getDate'));
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(isoDate);
   });
}
```

Haven't used jQuery in a while so syntax could be wrong.

Comment: I thought that the method **$setViewValue** update **$viewValue** (not **$modelValue**), does not it?